# Lifecycle and ​react variables (State and useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble understanding the react lifecycle, my problem might be the wrong logic (I come from php and web js)

Project summary: react fetches info from an api repeatedly (setInterval) with certain filters, where the filters are also the result of a request to the api.

There are stations, orders and currentStation (which comes from the UI)

My problem is that when dispatching a variable's set, it's not possible to immediately get that same variable.

```
// init app
....
useEffect(() =>
{
    listStations().then(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'setLoadedStations', state: true});
    });
},[]);
....

// events
...
useEffect(() =>
{
    listOrders(true);
},[state.loadedStations]);
...

// function
const listOrders = async (createJob?:boolean) => 
{
    let currentStationId = state.stations[state.currentStation].id;
    const orderList = await getOrders(currentStationId); 
    dispatch({type: 'setOrders', value: orderList});

    if(createJob) {
        setInterval(await listOrders, 4000);
    }
}

// UI
...
<IonButton
    onClick={
        (e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            dispatch({
                type: 'setCurrentStation',
                station: key
            });
        }
    }
>{station.title}</IonButton>
...
```

In setInterval it will always be the same state.currentStation where setInterval was created. Even if later the currentStation changes.

Another solution I tried was to add a clear, but it didn't work either because the variable isn't 'save'.

```
// App.tsx
const App: React.FC = () => {
let jobId = 0;
...
// function
if(createJob) {
    if(jobId) clearInterval(jobId);
    jobId = setInterval(await listOrders, 4000);
}
```

What is the correct way? Is accessing a state variable without a useEffect possible?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems strange `jobId = setInterval(await listOrders, 4000);`. What are you trying to do there. Also you can't return a value from `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Clarification

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` return values, but you can't return a value (`await listOrders`).

Comment: setInterval returns an id, which can then be used to end the loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Yes, I thought you were trying to return a value from the function you were awaiting